# Convert DataSnapshot to class object

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm newbie to Firebase Database and I'm following Google's Docs to retrive data from my database.
I have this structure:

```
root/
|
|--- 82JWZZZd***
|    |
|    |--- profile
|         |
|         |--- id: 1
|         |--- name: Arnold Schwarzenegger
|         |--- age: 70
|
|--- GB3FDPiw***
     |
     |--- profile
          |
          |--- id: 1
          |--- name: Sylvester Stallone 
          |--- age: 71
```

I want to retrive the profile information of a user and I have a Java class:

```java
public class Profile{
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private int age;

    public Profile(){
        // Default constructor required for calls to DataSnapshot.getValue(User.class)
    }

    public Profile(int id, String name, int age){
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

So, as I learned from Google's Docs I create a Listener:

```
DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(getUid() + "/profile");
reference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if (dataSnapshot.exists()){
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "" + dataSnapshot.getValue(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            // Profile prf = dataSnapshot.getValue(Profile.class);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

The Toast show me this:
`{id=1, name=Arnold Schwarzenegger, age=71}`
**BUT** if I uncomment the line

```
Profile prf = dataSnapshot.getValue(Profile.class);
```

my App **CRASH**.

I don't understand the difference with Google documentation. Can somebody help me? I'm struggling with this too much!
Error is:

```
com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Class com.companyname.myApp.FirstFragment$Profile is missing a constructor with no arguments
```

Comment: Can you please show your full stacktrace in the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have private fields, you need to add getters and setters. If you don't want setters and getters, use public fields.

Additionally, since your Profile class is nested inside your fragment, you'll need to mark it as `static`. So `public static class Profile{`. Also see this comment on Github: https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/issues/46#issuecomment-167373575

Comment: com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Class com.companyname.myApp.FirstFragment$Profile is missing a constructor with no arguments

Comment: Since your `Profile` class is nested inside your fragment, you'll need to mark it as `static`. So `public static class Profile{`. Also see my comment here: https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/issues/46#issuecomment-167373575

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen This I have to remember. Thanks.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen if you write your comment like an anwser i can mark it has correct...It works!! Thanks...

Comment: Florescu's change was also needed. So I've edited it to include this info.

Comment: Thanks to both of you!

Answer (score 1):

```
DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(getUid() + "/profile");
reference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if (dataSnapshot.exists()){
            //Create new collection<Profile> person;

            person=new ArrayList<Profile>();
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "" + dataSnapshot.getValue(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Map<String,String> td=(HashMap<String, String>)dataSnapshot.getValue();
            Profile prf =new Profile(td.get("id"),td.get("name"),td.get("age"))

            person.add(prf);

        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```